# Accessing Shared Folder from ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am trying to access shared folder from ASP.NET MVC site.

Below is the how I have link to shared folder from site

```
 file://fs04/Public/Intranet Files
```

Link from the site to shared folder is not working when we are browsing with `http://IPAddress:81` address but where as when we browse with `http://localhost:81` links are working.

FYI... My ASP.NET MVC AppPool is running with NETWORK SERVICE account.

Appreciate if could provide some inputs here.

Comment: Does `Network Service` have access to the files(s)?

Comment: Can you confirm if you're doing this in HTML (e.g. `<a href="file://\\server\share\whatever">`) or from .NET (e.g. `File.Open("file://server/share/whatever");`)?

Comment: I am doing from html. Anchor tag as you have specified